# tkinter widget manipulation

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I connect the submit button to another "window" so the information entered in tk.Entry() is entered in a specified label on a  2nd "window". I want the "submit" button to be what pulls up the 2nd window "anchored" in the main window from that I will have pointed the information in the entry to the label in the 2nd popup window.

```py
import tkinter as tk

#function that prints the entry
def entry_print(widget):
    name = widget.get()
    print(name)

#Setup for the window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Title_Name")
window.geometry("250x250")

#widgets
label = tk.Label(window, text = "Manual:", bg = "dark grey", fg = "white")
entry = tk.Entry()
button = tk.Button(text = "submit",
                   command = lambda e = entry: entry_print(e))

#widget placement
label.place(x=0,y=20)
entry.place(x=52,y=21)
button.place(x=177, y=18)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create additonal windows via [`Toplevel`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111195659id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) widgets. You can refer to the current contents of the `Entry` widget when creating the `Label` in the second one by creating a `tkinter` [`StringVar`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031100214id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) and setting the `textvariable=` option of both the `Entry` widget and the `Label` widget on the second window to it.

```
import tkinter as tk

#Setup for the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Title_Name")
window.geometry("250x250")

def new_window():
    new_win = tk.Toplevel()
    tk.Label(new_win, textvariable=entered_text).pack()

#widgets
label = tk.Label(window, text="Manual:", bg="dark grey", fg="white")
entered_text = tk.StringVar(value='')  # ADDED
entry = tk.Entry(textvariable=entered_text)
button = tk.Button(text="submit", command=new_window)

#widget placement
label.place(x=0,y=20)
entry.place(x=52,y=21)
button.place(x=177, y=18)

window.mainloop()
```

Here's a screenshot of it running:

[image: screenshot of it running]

Comment: No worries…you're well on your way to gaining the rep.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. It is much more simple comparitively.

```
import tkinter as tk

#function that prints the entry
def entry_function(e=None):
    name = entry.get()
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    tk.Label(win, text=name).pack()

#Setup for the window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Title_Name")
window.geometry("250x250")

#widgets
label = tk.Label(window, text = "Manual:", bg = "dark grey", fg = "white")
entry = tk.Entry()
button = tk.Button(text = "submit",
                   command = entry_function)

#widget placement
label.place(x=0,y=20)
entry.place(x=52,y=21)
button.place(x=177, y=18)

window.mainloop()
```

As a bonus, you can make the button such that when you press enter key after writing the name, you can automatically run the entry_funtion function using the code:

```
window.bind('<Return>', entry_function)
```

Comment: I was curious what would I add/edit to make the entry(s) show up in the same window preferably  "in line" .